# Trying to deploy to Hololens2 over Remote machine from Visual Studio fails

Tags: visual-studio, hololens

Ip address is already updated (with no portnumber). But I get this error, when I try to deploy to hololens over wifi. Developper modes are enabled (win + holo), no firewalls; same wifi. I don't know what to do more.

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
BootstrapForDebugging returned null instead of IPAddress & PortNumber of the remote msvsmon process.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------



Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       DEP6701: Bootstrapping failed with unexpected error: ArgumentException - Parameter cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: target [0x80070057] MRTK Tutorial
```

Restarted everything.

Its a unity project using the new MRTK. Deploying over USB is working fine. Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.2.1

I installed
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (2) (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.3.4 and did the same settings and now it's magically working (also in the Community version it's working.. since the project is the same)

[image]

Comment: Would you share more details about your project? What’s the development tools and do you use Unity or Unreal Engine? 

Can you provide the version of Visual Studio you are using? Have you tried to deploy via USB? Please refer to [Using Visual Studio to deploy and debug - Mixed Reality | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/using-visual-studio?tabs=hl2).

Comment: @ZuochengWang-MSFT Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.2.1 - Unity 2020.3.24f1 - deploying over usb in visual studio is no problem, but is over wifi not working

Answer (score 2):

It is still difficult to troubleshoot this issue based on current information. The root cause can be varied. However, after you upgrade the visual studio, this issue has been fixed. I recommend that you keep Visual Studio updated to reduce the occurrence of such issues and feel free to get [HoloLens2 support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens2-support) from Microsoft if you have any other questions.